# How can I specify which cipher lftp is using when connecting to a sftp server?

Tags: encryption, sftp, lftp

I'm using lftp to connect to an sftp server but I get a "no matching ciphers" error, and need to specify which cipher is used.

Using sftp the command to connect would look like this:

```
sftp -c aes256-cbc sftp://sftpserver:10
```

How can I connect with that cipher using lftp? I can't find anything about ciphers or how to specify which encryption to use and let lftp pass it to ssh. I'm looking for something similar to sftp's option -o that passes and option to ssh.

Comment: Doesn't the error say that there's ***no*** cipher that the lftp and the server can agree upon? You may need to upgrade the lftp or the server. Or what exactly is the behaviour of `sftp` without the `-c aes256-cbc`?

Comment: Without the `-c`-switch `sftp` I can't connect, but I get a message saying "`Their offer`" includes aes256-cbc, and when I specify the switch it works. I guess you're wondering why `sftp` does't use that cipher directly? I have no idea ...

Answer (score 2):

Read `man lftp` and see `set sftp:connect-program`. Here's my example (a shell wrapper around lftp) from which you can get idea how to use it, in my case I used lftp to sftp via a jumpbox.

```
...
sshargs="ssh -F ${tmpdir}/.ssh/config -J "
sshargs+="${JUMPBOX_USER}@${JUMPBOX_HOST}"

export LFTP_HOME=${tmpdir}
cat > ${tmpdir}/rc <<EOF
set sftp:connect-program ${sshargs}
EOF

lftp -c "
open -u ${WEBSERVER_USER},whatever sftp://${WEBSERVER_HOST}${DEST_DIR}
cd ${SRC_DIR} && mirror --dry-run -R --ignore-size -L --no-perms --no-umask
bye
"
```

Answer (score 0):

For interactive operations, you can just type this as your first command inside lftp:

```
set sftp:connect-program "ssh -c aes256-cbc"
```

Alternatively you can store this command in an rc file to load automatically, such as here: `~/.config/lftp/rc`